# Is there a better way to write this check to see if a value exists on a prop in react?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have this prop coming into my component, errors, which is an empty object if my form has no errors.  If there are errors they will be added to the object.  My question is, im checking for a specific property on the object, right now I'm checking to see that is not undefined.  Is there a better way to perform a check like this? Here is a snippet of the code

```
const SelectOverdrawnFunds = ({
  overdrawnFunds = [],
  options,
  setFieldValue,
  setErrors,
  errors,
}) => (
  <>
    {overdrawnFunds.map((select, index) => {
      const error =
        errors &&
        errors.overdrawnFunds !== undefined &&
        errors.overdrawnFunds[index] !== undefined;
      return (
        <SearchSelect
          key={index}
          name={`overdrawnFunds[${index}]`}
          label="Fund"
          options={options}
          TextFieldProps={{
            error: error,
            helperText: error ? 'Required' : '',
          }}
        />
      );
    })}
...
SelectOverdrawnFunds.propTypes = {
  overdrawnFunds: PropTypes.array,
  options: PropTypes.array,
  setFieldValue: PropTypes.func,
  setErrors: PropTypes.func,
  errors: PropTypes.object,
};

export default SelectOverdrawnFunds;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use optional chaining like this

```js
const error = !!errors?.overdrawnFunds?.[index];
//or
const error = Boolean(errors?.overdrawnFunds?.[index]);
```

or if you want to make strict compare with `undefined`

```js
const error = errors?.overdrawnFunds?.[index] !== undefined;
```

You can find more info about optional chaining on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: Well, as great as a solution this was, our code base does not support optonalChaining. Any other ideas?

Comment: actually, wrapping it in Boolean and removing the optional syntax seems to have done the trick